# Query to join multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table called `Entity` that only contains an `ID int` as the primary key.
I also have a number of tables of tasks (`Task1, Task2, Task3,` ...). These task tables have a number of individual columns, but have three columns in common:

1. a column `time_created datetime2(7)` with the default set to `getdate()`
2. their own `ID int` PK
3. the foreign key `ID_Entity` (which of course is the PK of the Entity table).

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Task1]
(
    [ID_Task1] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [describer] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [ID_Entity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [individual_task_value] [float] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Task1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_Task1] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task1] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Task1_timestamp] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [timestamp]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task1] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Task1_Entity] 
        FOREIGN KEY([ID_Entity]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Entity] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Task1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Task1_Entity]
GO
```

So basically one entity can have multiple tasks of different types.

Is it feasible to create one query that joins all these tables and thus gives me for one entity its different tasks (ordered by the date time)?

Say I query my Entity with the ID of 1 and get a list of all the task assigned to it:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------+---------+
| ID_ENTITY |     DATETIME     | TASK  | TASK_ID |
+-----------+------------------+-------+---------+
|         1 | 2020.03.01 17:30 | task1 |       1 |
|         1 | 2020.03.01 17:40 | task2 |       1 |
|         1 | 2020.03.02 06:30 | task1 |       2 |
|         1 | 2020.03.02 06:31 | task3 |       1 |
|         1 | 2020.03.02 06:32 | task2 |       2 |
|         1 | 2020.03.02 08:32 | task2 |       3 |
+-----------+------------------+-------+---------+
```

(The `ID_ENTITY` column here is pointless and just for demonstration)

Comment: IF you're using the `Datetime2(7)` datatype (which is recommended and good practice), you should also stop using the `GETDATE()` function (which only returns `Datetime` with a 3.33ms precision) and use `SYSDATETIME()` instead (which returns `Datetime2(7)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the problem looks like `UNION` to me.

```
SELECT ID_Entity,  [timestamp], 'Task1' AS Task, [ID_Task1] AS TaskID
FROM Task1
WHERE ID_Entity = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT ID_Entity,  [timestamp], 'Task2' AS Task, [ID_Task2] AS TaskID
FROM Task2
WHERE ID_Entity = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT ID_Entity,  [timestamp], 'Task3' AS Task, [ID_Task3] AS TaskID
FROM Task3
WHERE ID_Entity = 1

UNION ALL

...

ORDER BY [timestamp];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! Never used unions before.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `UNION ALL` will do the job:

```
select *
from (
  select [ID_Entity], [timestamp], describer, [ID_Task1] as task_id
    from [dbo].[Task1] where [ID_Entity] = 123
  union all 
  select [ID_Entity], [timestamp], describer, [ID_Task2]
    from [dbo].[Task2] where [ID_Entity] = 123
  union all 
  select [ID_Entity], [timestamp], describer, [ID_Task3]
    from [dbo].[Task3] where [ID_Entity] = 123
) x
order by timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! Never used unions before.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a recursive query for this